# If $a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f+g) = \sin(f-g)$ and $f= f_0 + af_1 + a^2 f_2 + a^3 f_3+...$, then finding $f_0, f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g(x)$ be a smooth function and assume that for each $a$ in a neighborhood of $0$ there exists a function $f(x,g,a)$ which is smooth in $x$ such that $a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f+g) = \sin(f-g)$. Assume also that $f= f_0 + af_1 + a^2 f_2 + a^3 f_3+...$ where $f_0 (0) = g(0)$ and $f_i$ are functions $g$ but they are independent of $a$. I want to find $f_0, f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$.

I am not sure where to start. So, I have no progress at all. Sorry.